# Unable to access cgroup in kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

With `docker run -it -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup`, I am able to see the `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/docker-.scope/memory.limit_in_byte`.

But if I deploy a Pod with the same docker image via Kubernetes deployment and hostpath volume mount, same is not seen inside the container.

```
  volumeMounts:
  - name: cgroup
    mountPath: /hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup
volumes:
- name: cgroup
  hostPath:
    path : /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Anyone seen the same issue?

Comment: What do you think, how can anyone read your post?

Comment: `kubectl get pods -o wide` See in which node your pod is deployed. `ssh` into your node, then check `/sys/fs/cgroup`

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. I can see data inside my pod. Provide your full Deployment.

Comment: @aerokite, yes you are right, the docker stats are visible under the kubernetes path, which I was expecting to be under the same path when run directly via docker  Here is the sample path under which the stats are found  `/hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods.slice/kubepods-pod5f48d59b_05a7_11e8_a01f_fa163e1c6cbd.slice/docker-8fe0417524b31a68fb0d4f822c17764bc665b5bdad105645bbdce7f9f70db821.scope/memory.limit_in_bytes`

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if the pod has the right RBAC privileges. For starters, I think it should be a privileged container